# ESP32 Wroom Devboard not powering up with external 5V supply

Tags: power-supply, arduino, esp32

Bought this ESP32 dev kit from Amazon and now everything is working until I wanted to use external 5V power supply. So far I have been using USB to power and upload the code to the ESP32 but now when I disconnect USB and try to power it with external 5V supply it just wont work (code doesnt execute)

https://shorturl.at/lEMUX

I have few sensors attached to GPIOs on the same board and I am using a buck supply to power up relay modules, PS set at 5V and the ground is set to common for both supplies (5V for sensors and 5V to power ESP32 Dev board)

I would want to power this using external supply and not USB. I am using VIN 5V pin and GND.

I can use 3.3V pin if its an option.

Things I have tried to far.
1- Relays and sensors powered by 5V have common ground with ESP32
2- Tried powering up ESP32 via 3v3 pin while relays being powered by 5V supply with all grounds common

Is it a Dev Board design flaw or am I doing something stupid ? My powersupply is very stable 5V and 1Amp, so power draw isnt a problem.

[image: ESP32 WROOM devboard schematic]

[image: ESP32 Dev board schematic]

[image: Relay module used]

Comment: There’s no schematic showing how you’ve wired it all up or what your 5V source is.